# How to catch errors from Goroutines?

Tags: go

I've created function which needs to run in goroutine, the code is working(this is just simple sample to illustrate the issue)

```
go rze(ftFilePath, 2)


func rze(ftDataPath,duration time.Duration) error {

}
```

I want to do something like this

```
errs := make(chan error, 1)
err := go rze(ftFilePath, 2)
if err != nil{
    r <- Result{result, errs}
}
```

but not sure how to it, most of the examples show
how you do it when you using `func`
https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5

Comment: If you want to wait til the `rze` completes - then you don't need to run it in a goroutine. Just run it normally and block.

Comment: @zerkms - it should run in goroutines, otherwise I don't have issue :)

Comment: Your code is blocking, running it as it is shown in a goroutine makes no sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use the return value of a function that is executed with the go keyword. Use an anonymous function instead:

```
errs := make(chan error, 1)
go func() {
    errs <- rze(ftFilePath, 2)
}()

// later:
if err := <-errs; err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: This is the way. I had to add a list of SQS queue listeners, each with their own handler function in a single processor and this way allowed me to listen for each queue in it's own goroutine with errors propagating into this error channel.

Answer (score 7):

You can use golang [errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) pkg.

```
var eg errgroup.Group
eg.Go(func() error {
  return rze(ftFilePath, 2)
})
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    r <- Result{result, errs}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle error from go routines using a separate channel for errors. Create a separate channel specifically for errors. Each child go routine must pass corresponding errors into this channel.

This is one of the ways how it can be done:

```
func main() {
    type err error

    items := []string{"1", "2", "3"}

    ch := make(chan err, len(items))
    for _, f := range items {
        go func(f string) {
            var e err
            e = testFunc(f)
            ch <- e
        }(f)
    }
    for range items {
        e := <-ch
        fmt.Println("Error: ", e)
        if e != nil {
            // DO Something
        }
    }
}

func testFunc(item string) error {
    if item == "1" {
        return errors.New("err")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: thanks, I saw this blog already. as I write it's a bit diffent as I dont use `func`

Comment: what are you looking for exactly? Be more specific please

Comment: assume that you have very simple function like `mine` (rze), how would you catch error?

Comment: go routine function or normal function? There nothing like catch an error(as in Java) in Go. Please refer the Error interface. In go error is either nil or non nil. nil meaning no error and non nil meaning some error. https://golang.org/pkg/errors/

Comment: how would you catch an errors for the function `rze`  `errs := make(chan error, 1)
go rze(ftFilePath, 2)`

Comment: err := go rze(ftFilePath, 2) doesnt return you anything. This code would result in a compile time error. Please go through the go routine basics.

Comment: yes I just need to know how to do it write, this is my question :)

Comment: Refer the latest edited answer. I have posted one of the ways how this could be handled